# Two Options menu in android Activity

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I am developing an app and I need to use **two options menus**. I searched and **found Popup menu** for the second menu. I implemented it successfuly but **failed to control its width and height** features. As I tried to adjust height of the Popup Menu in the theme it also distrubed whole app. My Question is **Can we implement 2nd OptionsMenu** the way we implement first one?

Comment: `two options menu`.. how you want it.. ?? any structure?

Comment: My app is basically a search app. I want two option menus one for search and one for settings. So when user click on search icon its option menu will be displayed and similarly for settings icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Very simple dude.. 
In one `menu item` set the `show as action` to `always` and add `submenu` and add menu item to it. Simple you get another menu. Add this as many as you want. :) For other menus add normally. Okie :)

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Menu1"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" >

    <menu>
        <item
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:title="Menu sub" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks Panther I know It looked childish to ask question like this, but google only respond to what you type but minds can pick from wrong words the true intention as you did. Thanks a lot!